# Find element in DOM after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

In a jQuery Tree, which is build dynamically, I want to run a function to find the right element. If the element is found, I want to run a click event.

The tree's children gets build when their parent's are clicked through a Ajax call. Therefore by 'search' function needs to wait for that Ajax to complete, and then look if the DOM element exist.

I can't tell my function exactly which ajax call it needs to wait on, so I thought I tell it to generally wait for all ajax calls.

Where's my function:

```
if ($("#treeview10 tbody tr[data-id="+id+"] .node-name").length){

    $("#treeview10 tbody tr[data-id="+id+"] .node-name").click();

}else{

    traverse_tree($("#treeview10 tbody tr[data-id="+id+"] .node-name"));
}


function traverse_tree(domelement){

    $("#treeview10 tbody tr .node-name").each(function(index, el) {

        $(el).click();

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            console.log('loop');
            if (domelement.length){

                domelement.click();

                return false;
            }   
        });         
    });

    if (domelement.length){

        console.log('found'); 

    }else{

        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {

            console.log('NOT found');

            traverse_tree(domelement);

        });
    }
}
```

This however does not work. The click event after the .each works, but it does not seem to wait for the Ajax calls to complete.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: can we see the html structure this call will dynamically build? - i think there's an easier way in which you wouldnt even have to look for it in the ajax call itself but i need to see the resulting structure first.

Comment: That's possible but I rather not link it on the forum here. Is it possible to link it to you privately?

Comment: um haha, would you be able to fill in this element selector with the target element you want to find? `$('#treeview10 tbody tr ....')`? that would work too

Comment: No because the last part changes all the time.

Comment: but is there a particular class that it always has? a particular anything? or, whats the farthest you can travel down the dom tree that is set before you get to?

Comment: Here's a example: http://ideone.com/JT4q4z. Those TR's get added when a node is clicked. So after a click, there may be 20 TR's.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your AJAX function, you should add your `transverse fuction` to the `complete` of the AJAX handling the change on the particular DOM.
*It is best to know which AJAX function is handling changes on a particular DOM*. You can use the **DEVTOOLS** [here](https://medium.com/@penseBien/devtools-is-more-than-i-know-debugging-js-72ef2f6d91b6).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxposturl",
  data: "data to be submitted",
  domeelement: targettedDOMElement,
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
   
  } 

  complete: function(data) {
   // This is where you call your function.
  traverse_tree(domelement);

  } 
  error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

The first click event does not wait for the AJAX stop call to be completed because it is placed outside the *block code in which the AJAX call is executed.*

```
function traverse_tree(domelement){
    var found = false;

    $("#treeview10 tbody tr .node-name").each(function(index, el) {
        
            if (domelement.length){
                found = true;
                domelement.click();
                console.log('found'); 
                
            }          
        });         
    });

    if (!found){
        
        console.log('Not found'); 
    
    }
}
```

If you cannot find the AJAX file,